# backing up django database with dumpdata

Tags: django, django-models

For testing, I would like to be able to save and restore app state. This would seem to be a very common requirement!

I find that I have to do

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude=contenttypes --exclude=auth > sitedata.json
```

in order for loaddata (after flush) not to complain about uniqueness violations and such.

At present this is just a magic incantation for me that I found in online searches. I don't find the explanations comprehensible.

I would like to know: first, why I have to exclude auth; second, what contenttypes even is, as well as why I have to exclude it. My concern is not that I can't do what I need to do now, but that I don't understand it and wonder if there are other corners of this procedure waiting to bite me.

Thanks for any information or links.

Comment: For what you are trying to do, I'd just work with the database directly and use your database client's dump and load data functionality. Django-Admin dumpdata is I think mostly used to generate fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

I had not so positive experience using `dumpdata` for database backup, and it wasn't designed for that apparently. I ended up writing my own management command that calls PostgreSQL pg_dump command. I would recommend using your database dump function directly.

Answer (score 0):

You exclude auth - because there might be some sensitive data, like user's email or password - so there is no real need to backup that data for **testing purposes** - tester can create its own user (more to that - he cant even now what is the password for your backuped user - password is hashed).  
"contenttypes" - this is a table, created by included into Django [Content Type Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes).

> Instances of ContentType represent and store information about the
>   models installed in your project, and new instances of ContentType are
>   automatically created whenever new models are installed.

It is created automatically and stores, so to say "types" for all models, translated into simple numbers. This is for advanced usage. I don't know exactly why it is recommended to omit while making dump data. May be that means that this table is used not in all projects or something else - so there is no real need to backup it, may be to reduce the backup file size. Or may be when tester make migrations on his computer - `contenttypes` table will already be created, so there is no need to pass that data.